# SQL Server Stored Procedures Execution difference

Tags: sql-server, performance, stored-procedures

I have SQL Server 2016. There are two absolutely same stored procedures with different names, but they execute differently. First completes in 17 minutes, other in 18 second.
First was created before Index on one of elements was created, but it was recompiled and cleared all plans from the plan cache.
The result does not change.

What problem it can be and how reconfigure execution plan?

Comment: Look at the stored procedure's settings like ARITHABORT, XACT_ABORT, etc.  They all affect the execution plan.  When creating a proc, the settings in effect at that time "stick" in the proc's metadata and influence the plan.

Comment: Did you use sp_recompile? On thing that you may consider when testing like this would be to place a WITH RECOMPILE in BOTH stored procedures to force the optimizer to fetch a new query plan per command. You may also want to UPDATE STATISTICS before testing. If the parameters are the same and the query is the same then there should not be a 17 minute difference as you noted above. On other thing, if your sp has many a parameters or they are used in non-traditional ways inside your statements you may want to use OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN (<--during your testing) to prevent parameter sniffing issues.

Comment: The statement of recompile: "EXEC sp_recompile N'ProcedureName';  
GO  DBCC FREEPROCCACHE WITH NO_INFOMSGS; "

Comment: might one be named with the prefix sp_  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To improve performance of stored procedure must be executed script lower. It can help to recreate execution plan.

```
EXEC sp_recompile N'ProcedureName'; 
GO 
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE WITH NO_INFOMSGS;
GO
EXEC sp_updatestats; 
GO
```

Comment: Did this work for you or are you just documenting what you have tried?

Comment: Yes, it worked. First time it executed about 2 minutes all next executions time was about 18 seconds.